# Eclipse Oxygen lags very often at very simple tasks

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, debugging, tomcat

For a while my eclipse is hanging at many points and freezes for some seconds even at the most simplest tasks. For example when i'm adding/removing breakpoints it takes like 5 seconds until i can continue doing my work no matter if i'm actually debugging or not. So because of actions like this, which are done very often, this problem incredibly slows down my workflow.

I know that there are millions of articles about Eclipse beeing slow but i did not solve my problem yet. I have searched a lot about how i can speed up my eclipse, this is what i've tried so far:

- editing eclipse.ini to the following form:

> ```
> -vm
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin
> -startup
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
> --launcher.library
> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359
> -product
> org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
> -showsplash
> org.eclipse.epp.package.common
> --launcher.defaultAction
> openFile
> --launcher.defaultAction
> openFile
> --launcher.appendVmargs
> -vmargs
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
> -XX:+UseG1GC
> -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
> -Xms2048m
> -Xmx4096m
> -Xverify:none
> ```

- Suspend all validators in Preferences
- Removed all Breakpoints
- Disabled all plugins on startup
- no special themes or other special stuff

These are my system specs:
- cpu i5-3570
- 20gb ram
- SSD harddrive

I'm using one single workspace and i create all my projects in there. Currently there are 9 dynamic web projects, but most of the time only 2-4 of them are open. I created a single tomcat instance for each project, each tomcat using the same runtime environment. It does not seem to matter if i'm actually running an app in a tomcat or not - even if all tomcats are stopped it still lags when adding/removing breakpoints.

Does anyone see what might cause my problems?

Thx

Comment: The size difference between -Xms2048m and -Xmx4096m might sometimes cause long GC.